# Transform / move one end of a path

Tags: javascript, svg

As a simplification of my code I have a number of svg rectangles. Each of these are connected to one another with a svg path or curve. 
The user can drag the rectangles. The code does this by applying a transform matrix to each rectangle.

Now I would like the path to adjust dynamically when a rectangle moves. Ie The end of the path connected to the moving rectangle also moves.

Is there some way I can apply a transform to one end of the path ?

Previously I have just redrawn the curves on mouse move events but in my more complicated code that gets awkward so I was wondering if there was a simpler svg feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way to do that in the general case.  You need to modify the path.

The exception, of course, would be the very specific case where you were dragging the rectangle vertically or horizontally, where you could perhaps get away with scaling the path in one direction.